# Remove/Edit Img classes in Wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress, class

So Wordpress is outputting this

```
<img src="http://site.com/path/to/image.png"; alt="Text"  width="600" height="100" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-168" />
```

However, I would like it to output this

```
<img src="http://site.com/path/to/image.png"; alt="Text"  width="600" height="100" class="full wp-image-168" />
```

Removing the align class and removing the size- part.

How can I go about this via a filter in the functions.php file?

Answer (score 0):

So here are a couple filters that may work for what you need.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_image_classes', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_image_classes', 10 );

function remove_image_classes( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(size-|alignnone)/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

I don't know if I got that preg_replace right. Try it out and see if it modifies your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that did nothing.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is because I am not using post_thumbnails in my code?